# Is it possible to execute a function in Ext JS that dynamically change forceFit?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I code Ext JS GUI for for multible screen sizes.

Is it possible to execute a function in Ext JS that dynamically change forceFit in grid?

That must executed at will.

I just using Ext JS 3.4.

Comment: I still need corrected aswerd because I am using Ext JS 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

In 4.2 you can try this:

```
grid.headerCt.forceFit = true;
grid.headerCt.doComponentLayout();
grid.doComponentLayout();
```

Comment: I am using Ext JS 3.4 and tested that code and it did not work. I am not going to make my whole software again with Ext JS 4.2.